# what is the valid syntax that can be written in curly braces { } in react jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I use conditional operators in jsx such as `{ var || var2 }`, `{ var && var2 }` it gives a syntax error.

What I want to achieve is something like

```
render(){
  return (
    {bool1} || {bool2} && <renderSomething>
  )
}
```

I do not want to wrap it in some `<div>`

Any more tips and tricks with jsx syntax will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the div to be wrapped then use React.Fragment like

Below are three possible ways of conditional rendering in your case

```
render(){
  return (
     <React.Fragment>
       {bool1 && <renderSomething>}
       {bool2 && <renderSomething>}
     </React.Fragment>
  )
}

render(){
  return (
     <React.Fragment>
       {bool1 || bool2 && <renderSomething>}
     </React.Fragment>
  )
}

render(){
  return (
     <React.Fragment>
       {bool1 ? <renderSomething> :( bool2 ?  <renderSomething>: null)}
     </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
render(){
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        { bool1 || bool2 && <renderSomething> } 
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

You can use React.Fragment.